# Trying to get a friendly url but nothing happens

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm trying to hide part of url and show only the variables like directories.

For example: Change from `https://somesite.com/users.php?user=Alex` to `https://somesite.com/Alex/` or from `https://somesite.com/users.php?user=Alex&tab=photos` to `https://somesite.com/Alex/photos/`.

My `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # hide GET variables from url for messages page.
    RewriteRule ^messages/(.*) messages.php?message=$1 [L,QSA]

    # hide users.php and transforming variables in directories.
    RewriteRule ^/%1 users.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

But, if I access `https://somesite.com/users.php?user=Alex` nothing happens and if I access `https://somesite.com/Alex/` error 404 is returned.

Comment: If you get error 500, there should be something in the error log. Otherwise we can only guess. My guess is that there is extra space in the last RewriteRule - this way it has 3 parameters plus options which is not valid.

Comment: You're right! Now is without errors, but, nothing happens when i'm enter in `https://somesite.com/users.php?user=Alex`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for users.php script:

```
RewriteRule  (.*) users.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This rule must be after messages rule in that order to work for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how could the last `RewriteRule` do what you want.
You could use this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ users.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ users.php?user=$1&tab=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Edit: You can also use mod_rewrite to redirect those who use the old url to new url. This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^user=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^/users.php$        /%1/               [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^user=([^&]+)&tab=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^/users.php$        /%1/%2/            [NC,L,R=301]
```

Alternative;y you can read `REQUEST_URI` variable in php (it should contain the address before rewrite) and detect if it was the old one. If it was, then redirect to the new one.

Comment: Oh, worked if I access `https://somesite.com/Alex/`! But, if I access `https://somesite.com/users.php?user=Alex` URL remains the same, how to do for when I access `https://somesite.com/users.php?user=Alex` replace to `https://somesite.com/Alex/`?

Answer (score 1):

Please write this code in your .htaccess file

```
    RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
    RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    users.php?user=$1    [NC,L]
    RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    users.php?user=$1&tab=$2    [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the easiest solution is to send every query to index.php?q=$1 or another script.php to manage the path:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

index.php can check both cases:

```
<?php

 $q = explode('/',$_GET['q']);
 $query=$q[0]; 


 if($query=='messages'){ 
    $message = $q[1];
    require "messages.php"; 
 }else{
    $user = $query;
    require "users.php"; 
 }

?>
```

Comment: Worked! (I changed the `index.php` to `users.php`). But, how to do to when I enter in `https://somesite.com/users.php?q=Alex`change  the URL to `https://somesite.com/Alex/`? Thanks bro.